# GPPSignIn authenticate asking for client_secret?

Tags: ios, google-api, google-plus, google-analytics-api

I have the following code:

```
- (IBAction)connectToGoogleAnalyticsPressed:(id)sender {
    GPPSignIn *signIn = [GPPSignIn sharedInstance];
    signIn.attemptSSO = YES;
    signIn.clientID = GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID;
    signIn.scopes = @[kGTLAuthScopePlusLogin];
    signIn.delegate = self;
    [signIn authenticate];
}
```

I get the following error after it's execution:

> Error Domain=com.google.HTTPStatus Code=400 "The operation couldn’t be
>   completed. (com.google.HTTPStatus error 400.)" UserInfo=0x15717010
>   {data=<7b0a2020 22657272 6f722220 3a202269 6e76616c 69645f72 65717565
>   7374222c 0a202022 6572726f 725f6465 73637269 7074696f 6e22203a
>   2022636c 69656e74 5f736563 72657420 6973206d 69737369 6e672e22 0a7d>,
>   json={
>       error = "invalid_request";
>       "error_description" = "client_secret is missing."; }}

I can specify client secret, but `[GPPSignIn sharedInstance]` doesn't have such property!
Google documentation says nothing about this case.

How to avoid the error above?

Comment: u were not added the client secret in your code , plz add that

Comment: Can you please tell me where should I add it?

Comment: can u show ur additional code plz

Comment: I don't have any additional code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with wrong Client ID - it was for web application, not for installed application.